# Sqlite insert java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: SRID)

Tags: java, spatialite, sqlite

I'm trying to connect to two DBs and then copy tables by inserting rows from one table to another through java using JDBC. I'm using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar plugin.The setup is in Eclipse Luna. I'm getting below error when I execute the java code. I queried it on SpatialiteGUI it works fine. Delete query is working fine, but insert. Similar to this issue but SRID is configured in my case, it's giving results in spatialite gui (as suggested by @BradHards).

[pyspatialite: Connot insert geometry](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76999/pyspatialite-connot-insert-geometry)

**java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: SRID)**

```
    import java.sql.*;

    public class SegregateDB
    {
      public static void main( String args[] )
      {
          //Both DB have same table structure.


          try{
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");


          String vanillaDBPath="C:\\all data\\MyBT\\NR dev\\jettyGeoHub\\BTPlantDB_sqlite\\vanilla.sqlite"; // target DB
          String PWAPath="C:\\all data\\MyBT\\NR dev\\jettyGeoHub\\BTPlantDB_sqlite\\BTPlantDB.sqlite"; // Source DB

          Connection connOldDb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ PWAPath);
          //add connection to vanilla DB.

          //newDbName = newDbName + "auftraege.db";
          Connection connNewDb = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+ vanillaDBPath);

          connNewDb.prepareStatement("ATTACH DATABASE \"" + PWAPath + "\" AS  pwa").execute();

          connNewDb.prepareStatement("ATTACH DATABASE \"" + vanillaDBPath + "\" AS  van").execute();

          connNewDb.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM van.attachment_ofl WHERE EXCHANGE_1141_CODE IN (SELECT EXCHANGE_1141_CODE FROM pwa.attachment_ofl);").execute();
          connNewDb.prepareStatement("insert into van.attachment_ofl select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute();

          connNewDb.close();
          connOldDb.close();

          System.out.println("Operation done successfully");
          }
          catch(Exception e){
              System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
              System.exit(0);

          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you do "create table van.test as select * from  pwa.attachment_ofl;? If you can, can you also insert rows into this new van.test?

Comment: Can you specify a bit more about which version(s) of spatialite you're using, and show where you are loading the spatialite extension?

Comment: @user30184 Yes I'm able to execute 
connNewDb.prepareStatement(" create table van.test as select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute();

But the "connNewDb.prepareStatement("insert into van.attachment_ofl select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute();" is giving the same error as mentioned earlier.

Comment: @BradHards I'm using version 4.2.0

Comment: @BradHards I'm using version 4.2.0.
By spatialite extension do you mean the jar file for sqlite-jdbc.jar or something else? Sorry I'm new to this :(

Comment: @user30184 I tried below steps:
1)Drop the table connNewDb.prepareStatement(" drop table van.attachment_ofl;").execute();

2) Create it 
      //connNewDb.prepareStatement(" create table van.attachment_ofl as select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute();

3) Then execute the insert query connNewDb.prepareStatement("insert into van.attachment_ofl select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute();

then, it is working. 

I always get one error in spatialiteGUI "SQLite SQL error: no such module: VirtualSpatialIndex."

Are these issues related anyways?

Comment: You have to load the spatialite extension. Spatialite is not part of sqlite, so where is it coming from? It doesn't leap into your code by magic :-)

Comment: @bradHards But why it is working after 

 I tried below steps: 1)Drop the table connNewDb.prepareStatement(" drop table van.attachment_ofl;").execute(); 2) Create it //connNewDb.prepareStatement(" create table van.attachment_ofl as select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute(); 3) Then execute the insert query connNewDb.prepareStatement("insert into van.attachment_ofl select * from pwa.attachment_ofl;").execute(); 


and any help in loading the spatialite extension?

Comment: trying to follow this tutorial http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/java.html will update you @bradHards :)